# "500 Error: Failed to establish a backside connection" - Bluemix Selenium Tests

Tags: java, selenium, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I have deployed a simple web based project which runs basic test automation on browserstack (test environment) via IBM Cloud.

URL : https://gaiaautomation0.au-syd.mybluemix.net/

The tests are executed by a call from the web page and an overlay is displayed when the tests are executing (Ajax call).

During execution, IBM Cloud times out randomly at different test steps with the console error below however the tests are still getting executed. Is there a way to stop the 500 error shown below.

> Error in browser: 500 Error: Failed to establish a backside connection
>
> **Error on console** :  2018-02-08T22:54:38.56+0530 [RTR/8] OUT gaiaautomation0.au-syd.mybluemix.net - [2018-02-08T17:22:37.569+0000]
>   "GET
>   /home?squadInput=CPI_Squad&featureFileInput=ABO_Increase_Watson&revenueFeatureFileInput=
>   HTTP/1.1" 502 0 67 "https://gaiaautomation0.au-syd.mybluemix.net/"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 1 0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36" "130.198.74.114:13610"
>   "130.198.80.122:63237" x_forwarded_for:"71.198.43.235"
>   x_forwarded_proto:"https"
>   vcap_request_id:"227ae9bf-40dd-4574-7931-967ed1a3ac51"
>   response_time:120.998508302 app_id:"7bc9c303-4ff6
>   e2e-9978-6f88d88a0bf9" app_index:"0"
>   x_global_transaction_id:"1936661453" true_client_ip:"-"
>   x_b3_traceid:"1fdd5d96f5688475" x_b3_spanid:"1fdd5d96f5688475"
>   x_b3_parentspanid:"-"  2018-02-08T22:54:38.56+0530 [RTR/8] OUT 
>   2018-02-08T22:54:40.02+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT xpath :
>   (//INPUT[@value=' Edit '])[1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens when there is no activity happening between IBM Cloud an your app. Increase the timeout from server.xml. Its usually set as 2 minutes by default