# How to increase timeout for long-running request on IBM Cloud / Cloud Foundry

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

**How can I modify the server configuration to increase the timeout for a Cloud Foundry app in IBM Cloud?**

I have a Python/Flask service on IBM Cloud/Cloud Foundry that may take over a minute to complete. The server sends a time-out error after one minute.

**The error returned by the server is**:
"500: Failed to establish a backside connection"
This message also appears in another thread: ["500 Error: Failed to establish a backside connection" - Bluemix Selenium Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48734553/500-error-failed-to-establish-a-backside-connection-bluemix-selenium-tests). And the answer posits that it is due to a server-side timout, which can be remedied by updating server.xml.

**How it is called**:
The service exposes a Swagger page. Using that page, an HTTPS POST message is sent to the service.

**Stack trace from the log**.
Swagger page is successfully rendered, but the POST initiated on the Swagger page fails:

```
2019-04-01T10:44:17.33-0400 [RTR/26] OUT my-impressive-gorilla.mybluemix.net - [2019-04-01T14:44:17.324+0000] "GET /fling/swaggerui/bower/swagger-ui/dist/images/throbber.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 0 9257 "https://my-impressive-gorilla.mybluemix.net/fling/swaggerui/bower/swagger-ui/dist/css/screen.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0" "10.184.41.5:33560" "169.61.175.148:61088" x_forwarded_for:"76.28.50.116, 10.184.41.5" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"81f863be-45e2-493d-7242-a253c67ccf21" response_time:0.011886681 app_id:"d457efd5-c189-40c5-8735-9705df905a1e" app_index:"0" x_global_transaction_id:"201956637" true_client_ip:"-" x_b3_traceid:"00ca96251beb2316" x_b3_spanid:"00ca96251beb2316" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"
   2019-04-01T10:44:17.33-0400 [RTR/26] OUT 
   [31m2019-04-01T10:44:17.81-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR 2019-04-01 14:44:17,810 - INFO - In ClusterText post()[0m
   [31m2019-04-01T10:44:18.11-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR 2019-04-01 14:44:18,110 - INFO - Coverage value is False[0m
   [31m2019-04-01T10:44:18.17-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR 2019-04-01 14:44:18,173 - INFO - Finding cluster labels...[0m
   2019-04-01T10:45:18.73-0400 [RTR/19] OUT my-impressive-gorilla.mybluemix.net - [2019-04-01T14:44:17.786+0000] "POST /fling/foo/cluster?coverage=false&n=3 HTTP/1.1" 200 286916 2618 "https://my-impressive-gorilla.mybluemix.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0" "10.184.41.4:29822" "169.61.175.148:61088" x_forwarded_for:"76.28.50.116, 10.184.41.4" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"fe9f1113-15b1-4c70-4228-14d06f1b596a" response_time:60.948784175 app_id:"d457efd5-c189-40c5-8735-9705df905a1e" app_index:"0" x_global_transaction_id:"61198623" true_client_ip:"-" x_b3_traceid:"4a22ac06486368a0" x_b3_spanid:"4a22ac06486368a0" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"
   2019-04-01T10:45:18.73-0400 [RTR/19] OUT 
   [31m2019-04-01T10:45:18.73-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR 10.247.195.155 - - [01/Apr/2019 14:45:18] "POST /fling/foo/cluster?coverage=false&n=3 HTTP/1.1" 200 -[0m
   [31m2019-04-01T10:55:55.25-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR 2019-04-01 14:55:55,236 - INFO - In ClusterText post()[0m
   [31m2019-04-01T10:55:55.25-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR 2019-04-01 14:55:55,242 - INFO - Coverage value is False[0m
   [31m2019-04-01T10:55:55.25-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR 2019-04-01 14:55:55,242 - INFO - Finding cluster labels...[0m
   2019-04-01T10:57:56.22-0400 [RTR/17] OUT my-impressive-gorilla.mybluemix.net - [2019-04-01T14:55:55.215+0000] "POST /fling/foo/cluster?coverage=false&n=3 HTTP/1.1" 499 163880 22 "https://my-impressive-gorilla.mybluemix.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0" "10.184.41.4:19579" "169.61.175.148:61088" x_forwarded_for:"76.28.50.116, 10.184.41.4" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"b765485a-b01e-4c02-49e5-e7d80e185d8f" response_time:121.010467641 app_id:"d457efd5-c189-40c5-8735-9705df905a1e" app_index:"0" x_global_transaction_id:"3327642733" true_client_ip:"-" x_b3_traceid:"5fbbd30cc568244f" x_b3_spanid:"5fbbd30cc568244f" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"
   2019-04-01T10:57:56.22-0400 [RTR/17] OUT
```

Comment: Can you add recent logs here? Command `ibmcloud cf logs <appname> --recent`

Comment: You need to provide more information on how your app receives the service request. is it a HTML request? Is it a REST request? Is it your app that sends a time-out ?  Does your app receive the time-out ?